# Run "sbt show subproject/dependencyClasspathAsJars" from shell

Tags: scala, sbt

In my multi-project build, I can list all dependencies of one of my subproject:

```
$ sbt
[info] ...
sbt:MyProject> show subproject2/dependencyClasspathAsJars
/path/jar1:/path/jar2:...:/home/.../MyProject/build/subproject1.jar
sbt:MyProject>
```

However, I'd need to run this in CI, but...:

```
$ sbt show subproject2/dependencyClasspathAsJars                                                                          
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/.../plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /home/.../MyProject/project
[info] Loading settings for project MyProject from build.sbt,modules.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to MyProject (in build file:/home/.../MyProject/)
[error] Not a valid command: show (similar: shell)
[error] Expected whitespace character
[error] Not a valid project ID: show
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: show (similar: showTiming, sLog, ps)
[error] show
[error]     ^
```

**To get this classpath from (shell) command line, what should I do?** I'm using sbt 1.2.8 & scala 2.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`show dependencyClasspathAsJars` needs to be passed to sbt *as a single argument*. With common shells, this works:

```
$ sbt "project subproject2" "show dependencyClasspathAsJars"
```

`project subproject2` selects your subproject and `show dependencyClasspathAsJars` computes the task on the subproject.

Comment: Also, try `export dependencyClasspathAsJars` which gives  that jar list in a better format IMHO.